# How do I get this jQuery autocomplete code to work in FireFox?

Tags: jquery, xml, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete

Hey guys,
I've got this jQuery code which works in Chrome and Safari but not on IE or FireFox. What could be wrong with it?

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {
    var myArr = [];

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "airports.xml", 
        dataType: "xml",
        success: parseXml,
        complete: setupAC,
        failure: function(data) {
            alert("XML File could not be found");
            }
    });

    function parseXml(xml)
    {
        //find every query value
        $(xml).find("airport").each(function()
        {
            myArr.push($(this).attr("label"));
        }); 
    }

    function setupAC() {
        $("input#depart_from").autocomplete({
                source: myArr,
                minLength: 1,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $("input#depart_from").val(ui.item.value);
                    $("#submitform").submit();
                }
        });
    }
});

</script>
```

And here is my input element

```
<input id="depart_from" type="text" name="depart_from" placeholder="Depart from"/>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What errors do you get? What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: That is the weird part. I don't get any errors in Firebug. Really strange. The dropdown autocomplete list doesn't show. It shows in Safari and Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, revised answer. Changed dataType to html and fix errors in xml document:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var myArr = [];
function parseXml(xml)
{
    //find every query value
    $(xml).find("airport").each(function()
    {
        myArr.push($(this).attr("label"));
    }); 
}

function setupAC() {
    $("input#depart_from").autocomplete({
            source: myArr,
            minLength: 1,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                $("input#depart_from").val(ui.item.value);
                $("#submitform").submit();
            }
    });
}

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "airports.xml", 
    dataType: "html",
    success: parseXml,
    complete: setupAC,
    failure: function(data) {
        alert("XML File could not be found");
        }
});


});
```

Comment: didn't help! Any other suggestions?

Comment: I made a jsfiddle for it. Can you send a link to a sample xml file? I can plug that in and see if it shows any issues.

Comment: I'm getting an xml parse error when I try to run it in FF. Do you see this error in Firebug? It is what I am getting: XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{dd117028-da50-7b48-9a90-51f90c48ea9e} Line Number 1, Column 1:

Comment: I think I found it: label='Coeur d'Alene'

Comment: Don't see that in Firebug! That is strange. Maybe there is something wrong with the xml-file. Could that be it?

Comment: OK, I got it working in FF4 Mac: http://www.jensbits.com/demos/autocomplete/indexXml.html but I fixed the xml and changed the dataType to HTML. Look at the source of my example.

Comment: Fix the xml errors with proper nesting of quotes: label="Coeur d'Alene" There may be one more instance of single quotes. Change the dataType to html. I revised my answer, if it works for you please mark as answered.

Comment: Awesome! You're welcome. I put a console.log in on my example page. Be sure to take that out. I don't think IE likes it.