# Airport autocomplete by City name and airport code

Tags: jquery-ui-autocomplete

We are developing an travel web app and here is some scenario with airport code autocomplete, which i am struggling to get it working as intended. I am getting all the airport codes & city name from xml and bind it to text input. The scenario is When user types "**Mani**" It should display **"All cities start with Mani"**, instead it is displaying all cities which contains that term mani (See this image : https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zn3c.jpg). But if user directly inputs airport code, it will display results, obviously.

So for that, i used that **monkey patch for autocomplete**, now it is working fine. But now, when user types the airport code like "JFK,LHR,MNL" it is not giving any results.

This is the way all travel sites working and i need your help in achieving this. Thanks in advance. Here is my code with monkey patch for autocomplete.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var myArr = [];
    function parseXml(xml)
    {
        $(xml).find("CityAirport").each(function()
        {
            myArr.push($(this).attr("CityName")+"-"+$(this).attr("AirportCode"));
        }); 
    }

    function setupAC() {
        $("#from").autocomplete({
                source: myArr,
                minLength: 1,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $("#from").val(ui.item.value);
                }
        });
        $("#to").autocomplete({
                source: myArr,
                minLength: 1,
                select: function(event, ui) {
                    $("#to").val(ui.item.value);
                }
        });
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xmlFiles/flight/AirportCode.xml", 
        dataType: "html",
        success: parseXml,
        complete: setupAC,
        failure: function(data) {
            alert("XML File could not be found");
        }
    });
});
function hackAutocomplete(){    
    $.extend($.ui.autocomplete, {
        filter: function(array, term){
            var matcher = new RegExp("^" + term, "i");

            return $.grep(array, function(value){
                return matcher.test(value.value);// || value.value || value);
            });                     
        }
    });
}
```

This code was taken from this thread : [Autocomplete from SOF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6169954/how-do-i-get-this-jquery-autocomplete-code-to-work-in-firefox)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to split the two data properties and use a callback function as source param, more or less like this ([see it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/awyG6/2/)):

```
var source = [
    { name: 'New york', code: 'JFK'},
    { name: 'Other name', code: 'BLA'},
    { name: 'Rome', code: 'FCO'}
];
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
        var searchTerm = request.term.toLowerCase();
        var ret = [];
        $.each(source, function(i, airportItem){
            //Do your search here...
            if (airportItem.code.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) !== -1 || airportItem.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchTerm) === 0)
                ret.push(airportItem.name + ' - ' + airportItem.code);
        });

        response(ret);
    }
});​
```